# Обновление данных в таблице частями

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно выполнить обновление полей `comments`, `receipt`, `date` в таблице `test_p` из таблицы `ORG_P` частями (примерно по 100 000 уникальных записей), т.к. в таблице `ORG_P` более 3 млн. записей.

Т.е первый раз обновляем 100К записей, а во второй раз обновляем другие 100К, не входящие в первый раз.

Есть пример, но он обновляет все записи по `max("record_id")`:

```
declare
  v_count_rows number := 2; --кол-во обновляемых записей
  v_maxid   number; 
  v_id      number := 0; - начальное значение
begin
  select max("record_id") into v_maxid from test_p;
  while v_id < v_maxid loop

    update test_p t1
       set ("comments", "receipt", "date") =
           (select t2."comments", t2."receipt", t2."period_date"
              from org_p t2
             where "record_id" between v_id and
                   least(v_maxid, v_id + v_count_rows)
               and t1."record_id" = t2."record_id")

--пров-ка на существование     
where exists (select 1
              from ORG_P t2
             where "record_id" between v_id and
                   least(v_maxid, v_id + v_count_rows)
               and t1."record_id" = t2."record_id");             

    v_id := v_id + v_count_rows;    
  end loop;  
  commit;  
end;
```

Comment: пример как раз и обновляет частями!  По v_count_rows  строк за раз! Циклом.

Comment: Это понятно,вопрос некорректно поставил.Обновляет, но долго очень - 1 млн. записей более 5 часов. Решение https://toster.ru/q/224626

Answer (score 1):

Думаю нехорошо sql заставлять вычыслять для каждой строчки 
выражение которое от этой строчки ни как не зависит 
least(v_maxid, v_id + v_count_rows)
лучше заведите еще одну переменную

```
declare
  v_mmax number; 
begin
  v_mmax := least(v_maxid, v_id + v_count_rows)
```

а в запросе используете вместо `least(v_maxid, v_id + v_count_rows)`
просто `v_mmax`.

Answer (score 1):

3 миллиона строк, это не много. Можно просто переписать UPDATE та MERGE

```
MERGE INTO t1
USING (SELECT rd_id, comment, receipt, period_date FROM) t2
ON    (t1.rd_id = t2.rd_id)
WHEN  MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET   t1.comments = t2.comment,
      t1.receipt = t2.receipt,
      t1.period_date = t2.period_date;
```

Comment: Хм..не сразу увидел в комментариях к вопросу, что проблема решена. Пускай и тут будет, чтобы люди не прыгали между ресурсами